# Showing $A=F(K)$ where $F(K)$ denotes the set of complex-valued functions on $K$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $K$ is a finite set and $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of functions that is a self-adjoint algebra, separates points, and vanishes nowhere. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ has to contain every complex function on $K$.

a Self-Adjoint Algebra means that for $f,g\in \mathcal{A}$, $c\in \mathbb{C}$ it follows that $f+g\in \mathcal{A}$, $f\cdot g\in \mathcal{A}$, $cf\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\bar{f}\in \mathcal{A}$.

Separates Points means $\forall x,y\in K$ with $x\neq y$. $\exists f\in \mathcal{A}$ so that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Vanishes Nowhere means $\forall x\in K, \exists f\in \mathcal{A}$ so that $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: This is the Stone Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Does $A$ have a norm?  A unit?  I'm not sure your result is correct without at least one of these assumptions.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the cases where $|K| \leq 1$ are easy, so suppose $|K| \geq 2$. It suffices to show that for every distinct pair of points $p, q \in K$ that there is a function $f_{p, q} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f_{p, q}(p) \neq 0$ and $f_{p, q}(q) = 0$, since then the indicator function $\delta_p$ may be written as a re-normalisation of the function
$ D_p := \prod_{q \neq p} f_{p, q}$.

Given a pair of distinct points $p, q \in K$, such a function $f_{p, q} \in \mathcal{A}$ does always exist. By the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ separates points, there exists a $g \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $g(p) \neq g(q)$. We then have two cases:

1. If $g(p) \neq 0$, then set $f_{p, q} = g^2 - g(q)g$.
2. If $g(p) = 0$ (and so $g(q) \neq 0$), then set $f_{p, q} = h - \frac{h(q)}{g(q)}g$, where $h \in \mathcal{A}$ is a function with $h(p) \neq 0$ (which exists by the nowhere-vanishing assumption).